# Quotation marks in value of html tag attribute problem

Tags: php, html, quotes

```
<?php    
$myname = 'my name have quotation marks " <- here';
?>
```

And i try to:

```
<input type="text" name="newnameproposition[<?php echo $myname ?>]">
```

And html have a little problem becouse of:

```
name="newnameproposition[my name have quotation marks " <- here]"
```

Can anybody had this kind of problem?

Comment: question mark is not valid in the input name element

Comment: sure your not confusing name with value? sounds like an odd naming convention

Comment: @Dagon — Field names are parsed by PHP.  For example, `?foo[bar]=1&foo[baz]=2` will create a two-element associative array named `$_GET["foo"]`.

Comment: doh, missed the square brackets completely, php variables of course can't have a ? in them

Comment: Can anybody had this kind of problem? = If anybody had this kind of problem?
------------------------
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: But im talking about value of tag attribute, not about value/content of tag.

Comment: What do you mean? You should be able to do <input type="text" name="newnameproposition[<?php echo htmlentities($myname); ?>]">.

Comment: Ok its working with htmlentities(), and when i get it from post i use html_entity_decode() and i have proper value :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Little advice: watch out for charset coding in htmlentities and html_entity_decode ;)