# php multi Quotation marks

Tags: php, quotation-marks

I meet a headache problem. there are too many Quotation marks in my code make me headache.

I tried both of these method, but all the way are make links broken. I cheked it in `chrome`, In `elements`, I find the source code like what I add after `print($link);`.

How to solve the problem? Thanks.

```
$str = 'I\'m very "shock"!';
$link=<<<EOT
<a Onclick="javascript('$str')" href="#">$str</a>'
EOT;
print($link); // <a onclick="javascript('I'm very " shock"!')"="" href="#">I'm very "shock"!</a>
```

OR

```
$str = 'I\'m very "shock"!';
$link = '<a Onclick="javascript(\''.$str.'\')" href="#">'.$str.'</a>';  
print($link); //<a onclick="javascript('I'm very " shock"!')"="" href="#">I'm very "shock"!</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quotation marks in value of html tag attribute problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939193/quotation-marks-in-value-of-html-tag-attribute-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
$link = '<a Onclick="javascript(\''.addslashes($str).'\')" href="#">'.$str.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to double-escape your quotes :

```
$str = 'I\\\'m very "shock"!';
```