# Complicated case of escaping quotation marks

Tags: php

Here is the code I am trying to make work. As you can see, the code as it stands will call a javascript window and that works well. I now want to add the lines that are commented out, in order to make the window display or not display conditionally. I have tried many combinations of escaping quotation marks, or substituting them, but nothing works properly. Usually I lose the link action along with a display of some of the code attached to the link. Could someone have a look and see if they can propose a code solution.

```
<?php
//if ($review != 0) 
    //$yes2 =  

if ("{$row['passState']}" == 0) {echo "<a href='javascript<b></b>:void(0);'NAME='var basestring='window'+new Date().getTime();' title=' Results of quiz 'onClick=window.open('check/check.php?quizTitle=". urlencode($quizTitle) ."', 'width=1100, height=510, resizable=yes, menubar=no, status=0, scrollbars=1');> <p>Check your answers</p> </a><br />\n";} 


    //echo $yes2;                   
    //if ($review != 1)
    //echo "";
    ?>
```

If it is any help, I'm using this code elsewhere on the page and it works fine.

```
<?php                   
 if ($review != 0) 
    $yes2 = "REVIEW";
    echo $yes2;                 
    if ($review != 1)
    echo ""; 
    ?>
```

Comment: Doubt this is the issue, but - instead of `"{$row['passState']}" == 0`, it should just be `$row['passState'] == 0`

Comment: You've got the javascript code and HTML attribute all mixed together... cannot make head and tails of this snippet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quotation marks in value of html tag attribute problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939193/quotation-marks-in-value-of-html-tag-attribute-problem)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ("{$row['passState']}" == 0) {echo "<a href='javascript<b></b>:void(0);' NAME=\"var basestring='window'+new Date().getTime();\" title=' Results of quiz ' onClick=window.open('check/check.php?quizTitle=\". urlencode($quizTitle) .\"', 'width=1100, height=510, resizable=yes, menubar=no, status=0, scrollbars=1');> <p>Check your answers</p> </a><br />\n";}
```

Copy this as it is....

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for all the escapes, you should embed the PHP code in the HTML, not the other way around. Example:

```
<?php if ($row['passState'] == 0): ?>

<p>
    <a href="javascript:your_code()">
        Check your answers
    </a>
</p>
<br />

<?php endif; ?>
```

I had a hard time deciphering what your javascript was trying to actually do, but this will make it a lot easier for you to read and write HTML without worrying about escaping quotes, using `\n` characters, etc.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use addslashes method to escape quotes

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick needs to have a quote(s) after the `=`:

```
...f quiz' onClick=\'window.open('check/check.php?quizTitle=". urlencode($quizTitle) ."',
```